# Pandas removing duplicates based on selected columns

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, duplicates

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
   df1
       A   B    x     y
0     10  Z1  106   375
1     11  Z1  111   459
2     10  Z1  109   379
```

However I want to keep the unique rows based on column A & B. So my output is expected as: ( keeping the last one of the repeated) is

```
 df2
       A   B    x     y
1     11  Z1  111   459
2     10  Z1  109   379
```

I have used groupby, setting index and subset but nothing works:

I expected that if I use the following it will work, but not working:

```
  df2 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['A','B'], keep='last')
```

But I am not getting my desired output, both the rows with column A having value 10 is there . Help will be appreciated.

I am using Anaconda and Pandas version 23.4.

Comment: I getting the expected output , can not reproduced

Comment: I'm also getting the expected output.

Comment: I can't reproduce this either - try resetting/restarting your kernel and see if it works. (i.e. re-run your code in case you mistakenly already defined df2 in some way)

Comment: Thanks yes. I will check upgrading pandas. As I am unable to produce the expected output with the exact same code I wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to sort the columns the way you want. That way the last row (the one to keep is the right one).

Try:

```
df = df1.sort_values(by = ['A', 'B'}).drop_duplicates(subset=['A','B'], keep='last')
```

This will keep the last row as the row with the highest values for 'A' and 'B'

Comment: Thanks. I will check, but it seems even without sorting that works, not sure if the issue is with pandas version 23.4. Will check and keep posted.